# Pairwise Learning to Rank SVM - class labeled 0

Tags: machine-learning, svm, ranking

Recently, I am doing research about learning to Rank. Basically, we want to find the pattern for the sample as follows,

$$S = \{(q_i, d_{ij}), (y_{ij}) \}$$
where $q_i$ denotes the i-th text-based query, $d_{ij}$ denotes the j-th text document retrieved for i-th query, $y_{ij} \in \{1, 2, 3, ... K \}$ denotes an order between query $q_i$ and the document $d_{ij}$. The numeric vector $\mathbf{x}_{ij} = \phi(q_i, d_{ij})$ is often created based on pair $(q_i, d_{ij})$. Then, the sample is like this,

$$S = \{x_{ij}, y_{ij} \}$$

Pairwise learning to rank modify this sample as following form,

$$S' = \{ (x_{ij} - x_{il}), (y_{ij} - y_{il}) \}$$
In this light, we can see that $(y_{ij} - y_{il})$ equals to $\{ -1, 0, 1 \}$. Then SVM classification can solve this problem.

However, I don't understand why SVM can solve this problem directly. If the target data is $\{-1, 1 \}$, I think SVM can do it. But I read several article they just ignoring the class 0 and formulating this problem as SVM model.

Can someone give me the interpretation for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially we only consider $y_{qj}$ > $y_{qi}$ or $y_{qi}$ > $y_{qj}$ while creating the training data. And these pairs are generated only when one is greater than the other (either using relevance grade or click count). So there are no ties. Hence, we will never actually have 0 in our training data for $(y_{ij} - y_{ji})$. I understand that there can be ties, but handling them is a different problem.